# Null Pointer Exception for read properties file in Idea

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

after define a property file in idea 10.5 when i try to use it,compiler show me Null Pointer Exception!I try anything that i think fix it among change property file path,...
here is the code that i write:
thanks.
beginner programmer!!!

```
public class MainDlg{
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    public MainDlg() {
        try {
            InputStream reader=MainDlg.class.getResourceAsStream("propFile");
            properties.load(reader);
```

Comment: You have asked 4 questions and none accepted answers. Please accept some questions before asking more.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the `reader` is null. Make sure the path is correct.

If property file is the root then you should

```
InputStream reader=MainDlg.class.getResourceAsStream("/propFile");
```

Comment: I know reader is null but I don't know why!!When i get Ctrl and mouse over on filename, Idea high light it.

Comment: Can you share where .java and your prop file is? We can help then

Comment: ok!prop file is in src directory and MainDlg is in presentation package!I copy the file in this package but it's not fix yet!!!

Comment: I test it before but not work!I don't know where is the problem!! thanks

Comment: Is this a maven project? I think the problem is your IDE or Maven is not coping the files over.

Comment: No,It's java module project!I think so because when build and check the out directory propFile is not there!it must be there!??

Comment: You are loading via the CLASSPATH!!!! And your src directory is _NOT_ in the classpath. Configure your build so that non java files get copied into the classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream returns null if the resource cannot be found.  Are you positive that, relative to the location of the MainDlg.class file, there is a folder called presentation, in which is a file called propFile?

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream is `case sensitive`. Make sure that your file-name matches exactly.

Answer (score 0):

probably you resources (prop files) are not put into the classes directory. In any case here is a tip ;) just before reading the property, print the following:

```
new java.util.File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

This should give you a good idea of what is your actual current directory
Hope this will resolve your issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put the `propFile`? It should reside in the `Source` root, however IDEA will not copy it by default to the classpath as there is no pattern for the empty extension in `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`.

It's recommended that you rename the file to `something.properties` so that IDEA copies it to the output (classpath) and it will become available as a classpath resource.

If you don't want to rename the file, put it in some directory outside the source root and configure this directory as a library dependency in IDEA `Project Structure` | `Modules` | `Dependencies`, this way it will be available from classpath.