# IntelliJ: how to make non java files copied to the bin directory as well?

Tags: intellij-idea

My module contains some non java files along the java source files. When the module is built, the java files are copied to the bin folder (and included in the jar artifact), but the non java files are left out.

I need them to be copied as well (this is what Eclipse does). Note, that they do appear in the project tree view on the left, I did not exclude them in any way.

How can I make them get into the bin folder (jar artifact)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Compiler` | **Resource Patterns**.

This question duplicates/relates to:

- [copy jbehave stories into target directory using IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629223/copy-jbehave-stories-into-target-directory-using-intellij-idea/8629542#8629542)
- [IntelliJ, Akka and Configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333093/intellij-akka-and-configuration-files/9333259#9333259)
- [IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 does not copy SQL files to the out folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100690/intellij-idea-11-1-2-does-not-copy-sql-files-to-the-out-folder/11100804#11100804)
- [Add a properties file to IntelliJ's classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765998/add-a-properties-file-to-intellijs-classpath/3769608#3769608)
- [import images into an intelliJ Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359635/import-images-into-an-intellij-java-project/10359665#10359665)
- [Intellij - how do I add a text file to the resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556478/intellij-how-to-add-a-text-file-to-the-resources/7556624#7556624)
- [Null Pointer Exception for read properties file in Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101484/null-pointer-exception-for-read-properties-file-in-idea/7162823#7162823)
- [IntelliJ Idea - resource SQL files not being copied to target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134250/intellij-idea-resource-sql-files-not-being-copied-to-target/8136368#8136368)
- [Scala getClass.getResource() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133632/scala-getclass-getresource-returning-null)

Comment: In IDEA 12 it was changed to **Exclude** patterns (defaults to `!*.form;!*.java;!*.class;!*.groovy;!*.as;!*.flex;!*.kt`), so all the other files will be copied by default. This will make it a less popular question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there any bug related to this in IDEA 12.0.4? It seems that only rebuild copies resources to classpath, not make. BTW I had filed an issue also.

Comment: @Cemo try [12.1 EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Even though it was been changed to Exclude file types, the implicitly included file types **DO NOT** encompass all file types other than the exclusions. Thus, you still need to manually include your file type if you're not getting your resource.

Answer (score 7):

On IDEA 14.1.4, the xml file in `src/main/java/my/package` folder is not copied. My compiler settings are `!?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.aj`.

I changed the gradle file by adding:

```
test {
    resources {
        srcDir 'src/main/java'
        include '**/*.xml'
    }
}
```

It starts working. I am not sure if I have missed anything, but I could not find that part reflected on project settings.

If you are working with Maven, the following code should have the same effect:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

I posted it here as an answer, because it may help someone who has the same issue and the above answers may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck use external build in project compiler setting.

Comment: Where is `Use External Build`?  Or is that only in older versions?  I can't see it in 2016.2

Answer (score 0):

Using CrazyCoder's info about version 12 (which I'm not using), I added the following as my resource pattern which worked well:

```
*.*;!*.form;!*.java;!*.class;!*.groovy;!*.as;!*.flex;!*.kt
```