# Scala getClass.getResource() returning null

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```
val url: URL = getClass.getResource("com/mysite/main/test.fxml")
```

and it always returns `null` (or `Unit`). I have only two files in the project:

```
MyProj/src/com/mysite/main/Test.scala
MyProj/src/com/mysite/main/test.fxml
```

and when I run the `Test.scala` the `url` value is always null.

I just tried rebuild the project, I am using IntelliJ IDEA. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: how to make non java files copied to the bin directory as well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176969/intellij-how-to-make-non-java-files-copied-to-the-bin-directory-as-well)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have three options:

- take advantage of relative path to your current package (where `Test.class` is):

  ```
  getClass.getResource("test.fxml")
  ```
- you can use absolute path:

  ```
  getClass.getResource("/com/mysite/main/test.fxml")
  ```
- or load through the `ClassLoader` (note that it always start from root):

  ```
  getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("com/mysite/main/test.fxml")
  ```

In IntelliJ IDEA, make sure you have added `;?*.fxml` to the:

`Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Compiler` | **Resource Patterns**.

Comment: Nope, the same thing, it returns null. I've googled and tried those, but none of them work either.

Comment: @rFactor Try refreshing the project.

Comment: @rFactor: so it must be something with your IDE. All of the above work, at least when I am using IntelliJ and maven project structure. Also are you sure `Test.scala` has correct package declaration? The directory is not enough.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz yes the file begins with `package com.mysite.main` and everything runs fine, except that it doesn't find the file and yes the file does exist. What is "refresh"? I pressed "Synchronize" and also "Rebuild project".

Comment: The file is not copied to the "out" folder structure, although the files "Test$.class" and "Test.class" are. Is that a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176969/intellij-how-to-make-non-java-files-copied-to-the-bin-directory-as-well

Answer (score 6):

Possibly it's not being copied to the bin/ directory from the src/ directory?
This happens on recompilation, but if you drop it into the src/ directory after the program is already compiled, the IDE won't know.

Comment: this solved my problem. I just had to to sbt clean compile and then it could see the resources. Thanks for preventing me from wasting any more time on this!

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but I just had this same problem. The root cause was an incorrect rootProject.name entry in my settings.gradle. Once I fixed that, cleaned, and rebuilt my resource were able to load using getClass().getResource(). Hopefully that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work, you can try with **ClassLoader**:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("filename").getPath
```

The filename should be in the same directory layer