# Cannot read file from resource folder in Scala

Tags: intellij-idea, resources, pom.xml

I am trying to read a file "my_data.txt" that sit in my `/src/test/resources/data` folder.

```
––– src

  –– main

  –– test

   ––– resources

      ––– data

          ––– my_data.txt
```

I have the following piece of code to do that:

```
val filename = getClass.getResource("/src/test/resources/data/my_data.txt").getPath
```

When I compile it, the compilation went well, however, when I run the test in ducker, I am getting the following error message:

> 

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at (xxxx.scala:128)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FunSpecLike.scala:454)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpec.withFixture(FunSpec.scala:1630)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(FunSpecLike.scala:452)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(FunSpecLike.scala:464)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike.runTest(FunSpecLike.scala:464)
    at org.scalatest.FunSpecLike.runTest$(FunSpecLike.scala:446)


When I try to print the path that I am reading from I got `null` as an output.
```

### Another attempts

Apart from above I tried the following code:

1. `val ss = scala.io.Source.fromResource("/src/test/resources/data/my_data.txt")`
2. `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/src/test/resources/data/my_data.txt").getPath`

Also, I added `src/test/resources/data` to the resources in `POM` file

#### Finally

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133632/scala-getclass-getresource-returning-null) mentioned, I checked if I have the **`.txt`** included in the compiler ( I am using `MAC`)

Comment: Does `getClass.getResource("/data/my_data.txt")` work?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it does not.

Comment: Pay attention to the path itself. I commented with the path starting from resource directory (`/data/my_data.txt`), absolute paths are used in your question though.

Comment: That is what I have in my code:  `val fileName = getClass.getResource("/data/my_data.txt").getFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this resolved by using `getAbsolutePath` to get the absolute path. I pointed out to the `test.properties` file to have the `dataDir`. Here is what I did:

```
properties.load(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.properties"))
testDataDirectory = new File(properties.getProperty("dataDir"))
val file = new File(testDataDirectory.getAbsolutePath +"/data/my_data.txt"

for (line <- Source.fromFile(file).getLines) {
   println(line)
}
```

This does not means that is the *"best"* way to do that, but just in case that you face similar issue, above what I used to resolve it.